# What is 0x0000000000001413 <+244>: cmp DWORD PTR [rbp-0x70],eax mean

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64

```
  0x0000000000001410 <+241>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x74]
       0x0000000000001413 <+244>:   cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x70],eax
       0x0000000000001416 <+247>:   jne    0x149d <main+382>
       0x000000000000141c <+253>:   lea    rsi,[rip+0xbf7]        # 0x201a
```

what is the compare line mean how do i break it by gnu debugger

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x74]
```

gets the 4-byte DWORD value relative to the base pointer (probably a local variable on the stack) and puts it into `EAX`.
The following line

```
cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x70],eax
```

compares this value to the next, adjescent 4-byte DWORD value on the stack and sets the EFLAGS accordingly. Here, the ZF (Zero flag) is on special interest.
Finally, the line

```
jne    0x149d <main+382>
```

jumps to the address 0x149d, if they are unequal (ZF=0, ZERO? flag **not set**).
After that, the program continues with the line

```
lea    rsi,[rip+0xbf7]        # 0x201a
```

and so on...